# Haskell - depth for each node in binary tree using Reader monad

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

I wrote the following code. It is working and using the `Reader` monad.

Could you give me some hints about code style in Haskell ? Mainly, I mean monads -- I am newbie.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty

renumberM :: Tree a -> Reader Int (Tree Int)
renumberM (Node _ l r) = ask >>= (\x -> 
                         return (Node x (runReader (local (+1) (renumberM l)) x) 
                                        (runReader (local (+1) (renumberM r)) x)))
renumberM Empty = return Empty

renumber'' :: Tree a -> Tree Int
renumber'' t = runReader (renumberM t) 0
```

Comment: Perhaps this question would find a better home in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I want to show you that your idea is an instance of a more general concept - *zipping*. Here's a version of your program that employs a simpler and more functional style.

### Applicative Functors

Here's the definition of [`Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative):

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You could say that a type `f x` is a *structure* `f` containing some *values* `x`. The function `<*>` takes a structure of functions (`f (a -> b)`) and applies it to a structure of arguments (`f a`) to produce a structure of results (`f b`).

### Zippy Applicatives

One way to make `Tree` an applicative functor is by making `<*>` traverse the two trees in lock-step, *zipping* them together just like [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) does with lists. Every time you encounter a `Node` in the tree of functions and a `Node` in the tree of arguments, you can pull the function out and apply it to the argument. You have to stop traversing when you reach the bottom of either of the trees.

```
instance Applicative Tree where
    pure x = let t = Node x t t in t
    Empty <*> _ = Empty
    _ <*> Empty = Empty
    (Node f lf rf) <*> (Node x lx rx) = Node (f x) (lf <*> lx) (rf <*> rx)

instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f x = pure f <*> x  -- as usual
```

`pure x` generates an infinite tree of `x`s. This works fine because Haskell is a lazy language.

```
     +-----x-----+
     |           |
  +--x--+     +--x--+
  |     |     |     |
+-x-+ +-x-+ +-x-+ +-x-+
|   | |   | |   | |   |
          etc
```

So the shape of the tree `t <*> pure x` is the same as the shape of `t`: you only stop traversing when you encounter an `Empty`, and there aren't any in `pure x`. (The same applies to `pure x <*> t`.)

This is a common way to make a data structure an instance of `Applicative`. For example, the standard library includes [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList), whose [`Applicative` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Control.Applicative.html#ZipList) is very similar to that of our tree:

```
newtype ZipList a = ZipList { getZipList :: [a] }
instance Applicative ZipList where
    pure x = ZipList (repeat x)
    ZipList fs <*> ZipList xs = ZipList (zipWith ($) fs xs)
```

Once again, `pure` generates an infinite `ZipList`, and `<*>` consumes its arguments in lock-step.

The prototypical zippy Applicative, if you like, is the "reader" Applicative `(->) r`, which combines functions by applying them all to a fixed argument and collecting the results. So all [`Representable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.2.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html) functors admit (at least) a zippy `Applicative` instance.

Using [some `Applicative` machinery](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2), we can generalise the Prelude's `zip` to any applicative functor (although it'll only behave precisely like `zip` when the `Applicative` is zippy in nature - for example, with the regular `Applicative` instance for `[]` `zipA` will give you the Cartesian product of its arguments).

```
zipA :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
zipA = liftA2 (,)
```

### Labelling as Zipping

The plan is to zip the input tree together with an infinite tree containing the depth of each level. The output will be a tree with the same shape as the input tree (because the depths-tree is infinite), but each node will be labelled with its depth.

```
depths :: Tree Integer
depths = go 0
    where go n = let t = go (n+1) in Node n t t
```

This is what `depths` looks like:

```
     +-----0-----+
     |           |
  +--1--+     +--1--+
  |     |     |     |
+-2-+ +-2-+ +-2-+ +-2-+
|   | |   | |   | |   |
          etc
```

Now that we've set up the structures we need, labelling a tree is easy.

```
labelDepths :: Tree a -> Tree (Integer, a)
labelDepths = zipA depths
```

Relabelling a tree by throwing away the original labels, as you originally specified, [is easy too](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-42--62-).

```
relabelDepths :: Tree a -> Tree Integer
relabelDepths t = t *> depths
```

A quick test:

```
ghci> let myT = Node 'x' (Node 'y' (Node 'z' Empty Empty) (Node 'a' Empty Empty)) (Node 'b' Empty Empty)
ghci> labelDepths myT
Node (0,'x') (Node (1,'y') (Node (2,'z') Empty Empty) (Node (2,'a') Empty Empty)) (Node (1,'b') Empty Empty)

    +--'x'-+                      +--(0,'x')-+
    |      |    labelDepths       |          |
 +-'y'-+  'b'       ~~>      +-(1,'y')-+  (1,'b')
 |     |                     |         |
'z'   'a'                 (2,'z')   (2,'a')
```

You can devise different labelling schemes by varying the tree you zip along. Here's one which tells you the path you took to reach a node:

```
data Step = L | R
type Path = [Step]
paths :: Tree Path
paths = go []
    where go path = Node path (go (path ++ [L])) (go (path ++ [R]))

         +--------[ ]--------+
         |                   |
    +---[L]---+         +---[R]---+
    |         |         |         |
+-[L,L]-+ +-[L,R]-+ +-[R,L]-+ +-[R,R]-+
|       | |       | |       | |       |
                  etc
```

(The inefficient nesting of calls to `++` above can be mitigated using [difference lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list).)

```
labelPath :: Tree a -> Tree (Path, a)
labelPath = zipA paths
```

---

As you continue to learn Haskell, you'll get better at spotting when a program is an example of a deeper concept. Setting up general structures, like I did with the `Applicative` instance above, quickly pays dividends in code reuse.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go in and out of the `Reader` the way you do it here by using `runReader`; instead, you can rewrite it as

```
renumberR :: Tree a -> Reader Int (Tree Int)
renumberR (Node _ l r) = do
    x <- ask
    l' <- local (+1) (renumberR l)
    r' <- local (+1) (renumberR r)
    return (Node x l' r')
renumberR Empty = return Empty
```

However, you can write it even nicer by just using the applicative interface of `Reader`:

```
renumberR (Node _ l r) =
    Node <$> ask <*> local (+1) (renumberR l) <*> local (+1) (renumberR r)
renumberR Empty = pure Empty
```

Note that I have renamed your function to `renumberR` to emphasize the fact that it runs in `Reader`, but not necessarily using its monadic interface.

Comment: Is the `State` monad not more suitable here? Just curious.

Comment: I have no idea; it depends on what OP wants to do. The above is a straightforward refactoring of the original code. You would need to use `State` if you wanted e.g. the right tree to get numbers after the left tree.

Comment: He did say "it is working" so I was careful to keep its current semantics.

Comment: @dvaergiller: but do post a new question if it is unclear to you how you would use `State` to do that other kind of numbering.

Comment: Frankly, just passing arguments down here is the most obvious way to do it. I see no point in a reader monad/applicative if you change the contents on every recursive call anyway.