# How does the Reader monad's "ask" function work?

Tags: haskell

```
data T b = E | N b (T b) (T b) 


f :: T b -> Reader Int (T Int)
f (N i l r) = ask >>= \x ->  local ((-)4) (f l) >>= \l' -> local ((-)1) (f r) >>= \r' -> return (N x l' r')
f E = return E
```

I have a problem with understanding how this code works. Especially, how does `ask` know where the environment is (in our case just `Int`)?

To be more precise: I am an imperative programmer and in such languages it is easy. Methods can be called on any object like: `obj.f()`, or we have to pass data by argument when we want function use external data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reader Monad Purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178889/reader-monad-purpose)

Comment: This is the second or third question I've seen this week about binary trees and reader monads ([eg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474647/haskell-reader-monads-depth-for-each-node-in-binary-tree)). Is it from a MOOC course assignment or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short, hand-wavy answer. The `Reader Int (T Int)` value is essentially just a wrapped-up function of type `Int -> (T Int)`. In order to run that function, we first need to extract it. We do that with `runReader`.

```
data T b = ... deriving (Show)

main = let tree = (N 10 (N 8 E E) E)
           g = f tree
           h = runReader g
       in print $ h 20
```

(Typically, you would simply write `print $ runReader (f tree) 20`; I split it up to correspond to the sketchy analogy below.)

`ask` (defined by the `MonadReader` typeclass and as implemented by the `ReaderT` monad transformer used to define the `Reader` type) essentially retrieves the value of the argument passed to `h`.

In some sense, the `Reader Int (T Int)` is an object that contains a function `g` that calls a function `ask`. `runReader g` creates a new function which, when called, defines a function `ask` that simply returns its argument, then calls `g`. Now when `g` calls `ask`, it gets back the argument originally passed to `h`.

Comment: "The Reader Int (T Int) value is essentially just a wrapped-up function of type Int -> (T Int)"
It is not obvious for me, please explain :)

Comment: I was going to attempt it, but perhaps it would be better to point you to [this explanation](http://www.mjoldfield.com/atelier/2014/08/monads-reader.html) instead. It defines a `Reader` monad directly, rather than building it up from a transformer (that implements a type class) applied to the identity monad.

Answer (score 4):

That's kind of what the Reader monad *does*; it gives you an `ask` function, which "magically" pops up a value out of thin air. To actually *use* this, you need to call `runReader`, and give it the `Int` environment. The `Reader` type then automatically propagates that from the `runReader` call to each of the `ask` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend reading [this](https://mmhaskell.com/monads/reader-writer) first. Ask is defined:

```
ask :: (Monad m) => ReaderT r m r
ask = ReaderT return
```

and reader:

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
```

so

```
do
  r <- ask
  ...
```

is equivalent to

```
do
  r <- ReaderT return
  ...
```

So essentially `<-` just reaches into the identity monad, and grabs what ever value that will eventually be lifted by `runReader R = return`.

This enables global variables in haskell.