# The relationship between Data.Key and Control.Lens.Indexed

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

There are [`Keyed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-3.11/docs/Data-Key.html#t:Keyed) and [`FunctorWithIndexed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:FunctorWithIndex)   classes in `keys` and lens` libraries respectively.

Their member functions `mapWithKey` and `imap` seems to be similar, except that `keys` is formulated using type families, and `lens` uses functional dependencies.

When one should prefer one or another? Why `lens` doesn't use `keys`, is it because of type-inference? Are there some interesting history of development? As a library writer, should I write variants for both `Keyed f` and `FunctorWithIndex i f` containers?

Answer (score 2):

From the `keys` package readme—

> In practice this package is largely subsumed by the `lens` package, but it is maintained for now as it has much simpler dependencies.

Comment: Excellent question! The answer doesn't immediately occur to me. I'll have to sit and have a think, maybe work it out with a pencil.

Comment: @phadej `Zip` looks [a lot like `Applicative`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474647/haskell-depth-for-each-node-in-binary-tree-using-reader-monad/36480067#36480067) to me

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson the `Zip` and `Applicative` for list do extremely different things. I proposed a laws to narrow done `Zip` implementatons: https://github.com/ekmett/keys/pull/15