# Fold Tree Function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a fold function for a tree:

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf
                  | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
                  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

foldTree :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTree _ base Leaf = base
foldTree fn base (Node left a right) = fn a (foldTree fn acc right)
         where acc = foldTree fn base left
```

This code nearly works. However not always. For example it won't reconstruct the tree exactly the same as the original.

Comment: How are you calling `foldTree`?

Comment: One comment I didn't see below: while a right fold on a list uses a combining function with `(a -> b -> b)` type; a *left* fold on a list uses one with `(a -> b -> a)` type.

Answer (score 15):

GHC is good at folding things. The very structure of your type contains enough information for your desired in-order traversal strategy to be obvious to the machine. To invoke the magic spell, utter the words *"`deriving Foldable`!"* and GHC will write your function for you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
data BinaryTree a = Leaf
                  | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
                  deriving Foldable
```

Now we have

```
foldTree = foldr
```

An interesting corollary here is that you can vary the traversal order by varying the shape of the type.

---

While we're here, a note on your requirements. You want to implement a function, using `foldr`, which takes a tree apart and puts it back together exactly the same, equivalent to `id`. **This is not possible**. `foldr` provides *sequential* access to the elements of the `Foldable` structure, erasing information like the precise position of the element within the tree. At best, you can build a list-shaped tree, with elements appearing along the right spine:

```
toListShapedTree = foldr (Node Leaf) Leaf
```

What you want is a *catamorphism*:

```
cata :: (b -> a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
cata node leaf Leaf = leaf
cata node leaf (Node l x r) = node (cata node leaf l) x (cata node leaf r)
```

Note the extra parameter to the `node` argument! This specification gives the folding function access to the arguments of the `Node` constructor. Unlike `Foldable`, the type of a structure's catamorphism is specific to that structure. We don't lose information by viewing everything as a list. Now you can write:

```
cataId = cata Node Leaf
```

If you're dead set on using `foldr` for this, one strategy could be to take the positional information with you. First [label each element with its position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474647/haskell-depth-for-each-node-in-binary-tree-using-reader-monad/36480067#36480067), then in the fold use that data to reconstruct the tree. Seems like hard work to me.

Comment: That's great. However I would like to know how to code it myself. Just as a learning exercise.

Comment: See [the linked Documentation page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/753/foldable/2556/an-instance-of-foldable-for-a-binary-tree#t=201608271208410494162) for an example. (Also, I added a section to the answer.)

Comment: Isn't `foldl (\l x -> l ++ [x]) []` the identity on lists ? If so it preserves the list structure :)

Comment: @V.Semeria Yes, but trees are not lists. They contain extra information, which `foldl`/`foldr` discard. `Foldable`'s view of the world reduces everything to a list.

Comment: Indeed. To me a foldable object is just something you can convert to a list. Then you use the usual foldr on lists.

Comment: Rather, `foldr f init t == foldr f init (toList t)`. So a fold cannot use more information about `t` than is contained in its list collapse.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this kind of fold:

```
foldTree :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTree _ base Leaf = base
foldTree fn base (Node left a right) = foldTree fn base' left
   where
   base'  = fn a base''
   base'' = foldTree fn base right
```

This is, roughly, what is being generated by the automatic `deriving Foldable`.

The above is a sequential fold, which first folds over the left part, then over the middle element, then over the right.

An equivalent but less efficient variant is to convert the tree to a list with an in-visit and then apply a `foldr fn base` over the result. One can "spread" the `foldr` over all the list generation, recovering the code above.

Comment: Assume I created a Trinary (Ternary?) tree which was defined as 

`data TriTree a = EmptyNode | TriNode a (TriTree a) (TriTree a) (TriTree a)
  deriving (Show)`

How would I create a pre-order fold for a tree like this?

Comment: @Lombe That's not a comment, that's a question. You probably should post it as such, and clarify why you were not able to adapt the above code to your tree type.

Comment: @chi I was able to figure it out. However,I have a different haskell related question. If you have the time, I was wondering if you'd be able to help me figure it out. I just posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638198/haskell-deriving-a-list-from-a-p-tree

Answer (score 2):

I came here after struggling with an exercise in Allen & Moronuki's *Haskell Programming from first principles*. This question sounds like the same exercise, so, for what it's worth, from one beginner to another, here's what I came up with.

I see three ways to "fold" (or catamorph) a binary tree. When folding a sequence, there are two ways to do it: fold left and fold right.  One way is to start by applying the given function to (1) the head of the list and (2) the return value of the recursive call applied to the tail of the list.  That's a fold right.

The other way to do a sequential fold is to start by recursively calling fold on (1) the return value of the given function applied to the head of the list and (2) the tail of the list.  That's a fold left.

But in a binary tree each value can have *two* "subsequent" values, rather than one as in a list.  So there must be two recursive calls to the fold.  The call to the passed function thus can either be outside the two recursive calls, inside the two, or else between them.  If I call those each left, right and center folds, I get these:

```
-- Fold Right for BinaryTree

foldTreer :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTreer f z Leaf = z
foldTreer f z (Node left a right) =
    f a (foldTreer f (foldTreer f z left) right)

-- Fold Left for Binary Tree

foldTreel :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTreel f z Leaf = z
foldTreel f z (Node left a right) =
    foldTreel f (foldTreel f (f a z) left) right

-- Fold Center for Binary Tree

foldTreec :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTreec f z Leaf = z
foldTreec f z (Node left a right) =
    foldTreec f (f a (foldTreec f z left)) right
```

The first time I ever looked at Haskell was a couple weeks ago, so I could be totally wrong about everything, but that's the way it seems to me.

Comment: Switching `left` and `right` on the rhs of `foldTreel` corresponds to `foldTreer`. Switching `left` and `right` on the rhs of `foldTreer` corresponds to `foldTreel`. `foldTreec` stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to combine the middle point before going to the right subtree :

```
foldTree :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldTree _ base Leaf = base
foldTree fn base (Node left a right) = foldTree fn middlePoint right
  where leftFold = foldTree fn base left
        middlePoint = fn a leftFold
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't provide the correct answer either.

Comment: Please give an example where it fails

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I think I will just leave it as is for these reasons:

1. The type signature is given in the question so I presume that's what they want.
2. The question mentions "any traversal order is fine".
3. It works, just not in an order fashion eg. `foldTree (:) [] tree` will create a list of nodes but not in order. However `foldTree (+) 0 tree` creates a total where order is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching **foldl** one;

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldl _ e Leaf = e
foldl f e (Node x l r) = foldl f (f (foldl f e x) l) r
```

This will work for you

Also if you need **foldr** ;

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldr _ base Leaf = base
foldr fn base (Node left a right) = fn a (foldr fn acc right)
         where acc = foldr fn base left
```