# Haskell: Deriving a list from a P-Tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I am coming from a background of Imperative languages, so Haskell and functional programming are a pretty new concept to me.

I have a data type that builds P-trees, a tree with p children. It's similar to a binary tree except for the fact that the leaves have values but the internal nodes do not.

This is the data type I came up with (Kindly correct me If I am wrong).

```
data PTree a = PNode (PTree a) (PTree a) | PLeaf a
   deriving Show
```

I want to write a function that takes in a PTree and returns a list of the elements in the tree. This is what I have come up with so far

```
pList :: (Ord a) => PTree a -> [a]
pList PLeaf a = [a]
pList (PNode left right)  = pList left ++ pList right
```

I'm not getting my intended results. For instance, if I try to run the following code in ghci,

```
pList (PNode [PLeaf 5, PLeaf 6, PLeaf 7, PLeaf 8])
```

I am hoping to get a list of [5,6,7,8]. Could someone please give me a clue on figuring this out and guide me onto the correct path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data PTree a = PNode (PTree a) (PTree a) | PLeaf a
                   --   ^ One    ^ Two
   deriving Show
```

Here `PTree` is a tree where each internal node has two children (see 'One' and 'Two) and internal nodes do not carry values of type `a`.  A PTree does not have P children - each node has two.  How many leafs total is not specified by the type.

```
pList :: (Ord a) => PTree a -> [a]
pList PLeaf a = [a]
pList (PNode left right)  = pList left ++ pList right
```

Close!  try `pList (PLeaf a) = [a]`.  Your way makes `PLeaf` and `a` separate arguments instead of pattern matching on a single argument.

```
pList (PNode [PLeaf 5, PLeaf 6, PLeaf 7, PLeaf 8])
```

Mmmm.... less close.  Above you already showed `PNode` takes two `PTree`s and not a list.  Consider instead:

```
PNode (PNode (PLeaf 5) (PLeaf 6)) (PNode (PLeaf 7) (PLeaf 8))
```

Comment: Assuming I wanted PNode to take a list (so I could have a variable number of nodes), Would the signature of `PTree` look like this instead?
 `data KTree a =  KLeaf a | KNode [(KTree a)]
  deriving Show` ?

And if I modified my data structure to look like that, how would I change my pList function?

Comment: When I write something like this 
`kLeafList :: (Ord a) => KTree a -> [a]
kLeafList (KLeaf a)  = [a]
kLeafList (KNode [left,right])  = kLeafList left ++ kLeafList right`
It sort of gives me the answer I want, but this only handles a list with 2 nodes. How do I go about making this variable.?

Comment: Okay, so now I have this

`kLeafList :: (Ord a) => KTree a -> [a]
kLeafList (KLeaf a)  = [a]
kLeafList (KNode (x:xs))  = kLeafList x ++ kLeafList (KNode xs)`

When I run that, it gives me the answer I need [5,6,7,8 **** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function.

I can't seem to see which pattern I am missing.

Comment: @Kaylo I suggest turning on `-Wall`. It'll help you avoid some mistakes. It'll tell you you're missing the `KNode []` case. You can also avoid matching on the list altogether with `concatMap` or a list comprehension.

Comment: @HTNW Oh wow, thank you. There are so many errors in my code. lol

Comment: @Kaylo You `KTree` looks correct. For the recursive case `KNode subtrees`: you have a function `leaflist :: KTree a -> [a]` and `subtrees :: [KTree a]`. To apply a function to all the elements of a list you can use `map` as in `map leaflist subtrees :: [[a]]`. This will produce a list-of-lists, which you can `concat`enate to get a single list. Your explicit-recursion approach `kLeafList x ++ kLeafList (KNode xs)` also looks correct, provided you fix the other errors :)