# Making a foldl function for BinarySearchTree

Tags: haskell, binary-search-tree, fold

I've made a `foldr` function for `BinSearchTree`, but I'm not quite sure if it's correct. Do any of you see a problem here? Any tips? (I can't use deriving `Foldable`)

```
data BinSearchTree a
  = Empty
  | Branch (BinSearchTree a) a (BinSearchTree a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)


instance Foldable BinSearchTree where 
  foldr f x Empty = x
  foldr f x (Branch left a right) = f a (foldr f y right)
         where y = foldr f x left
```

Comment: Also, possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180630/fold-tree-function

Comment: @Chris The one at the bottom is the exact same, but I'm not sure if it's 100% correct

Comment: If you implement `foldr`, then Haskell will automatically implement `folldl`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So what's your suggestion?

Comment: @elKusn: well what should be the evaluation order? depth-first? breadth-first?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem from the code shown it would appear he's aiming for depth-first, but it would be good to get clarification on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fold the left subtree first here

`y = foldr f x left`

then you fold right subtree with left result as an accum

```
foldr f y right
```

and only after you fold a branch's argument

```
f a folding_result
```

To implement right fold you need to start from folding right subtree, then call a function on a branch's argument, and only then fold the left one

```
foldr f (f a (foldr f x right)) left
```