# Collect result from two monadic actions

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to tidy up the following into a nice one-liner:

```
(r1,r2) <- do
  r1 <- action1
  r2 <- action2
  return (r1,r2)
```

This snippet is itself inside a `do`-block. By looking at the type of `(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)`, I thought to use `liftM2 (,) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m (a, b)`. Now I can write it as

```
(r1,r2) <- liftM2 (,) action1 action2
```

which is less repetitive, but doesn't look very intuitive. What I'm wondering, and can't seem to find, is whether there is a standard combinator to join these actions and tuple-up their results?

Comment: `liftA2 (,)` is the standard combinator. [I call it `zipA`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36480067).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `liftM2` is intuitive but it needs some time to get used to. So, the answer is yes, `liftM2` or `liftA2` are the standard combinators for your case. If you really want a readable solution, there are a number of other options:

- `<*>` operator: `(,) <$> action1 <*> action2`
- `MonadComprehensions` extension: `[(r1, r2) | r1 <- action1, r2 <- action2]`

Comment: I like the MonadComprehensions approach - reads like a clean do-block.